# Cartoon on TV with a guy and a helicopter

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

There was this cartoon which has this human guy (the main character) and his friend, a helicopter (or maybe some other sort of aircraft).

The ending of the cartoon has them singing, saying "I am ..... and my best friend Kokie (cookie or a word that rhymes with cookie)... see you again .... good bye!"

The cartoon looked a bit like *Bob the Builder* and there were these other vehicles/objects that could talk too. I saw it in 2008 on the TV in Qatar, along with *Lilo and Stitch*, *Bob the Builder*, a cartoon with a brown fox that had a dog as the enemy (it's like a silent cartoon, *Feodrrr*?), and *Harry and His Bucket Full of Dinosaurs*.

The helicopter is not only his friend, there was another ship too.

Suggestions with Biplanes can also be useful since I have the vague remembrance.

Comment: So, this helicopter was intelligent, or could talk or something like that? And how certain are you that it was a helicopter rather than, say, a biplane? You say "or something", which makes me uncertain.

Comment: Can you edit in any additional information? What was the animation style (anime? classic western? 3-D/CGI?) When did you see it (both year, and time of day it was on)? Where id you see it (both the country you saw it in, and the channel is was on)? To confirm, the "guy" was human, and the pal was an object (a vehicle, possibly a helicopter)? Was the helicopter anthropomorphized (like the vehicles in *Cars*, for example), or was it just a helicopter? Could it talk, or move in unusual ways (pick someone up with a rotor blade, for instance)?

Comment: Did you watch these on the Disney channel?

Comment: no. I dont remember the channel though.. sorry

Comment: The thing I mostly remember is the song at the end which says "I am ........(the protagonist's name) and my best friend kookee (something rhyming with kookee) , see you again...good bye...!" a male sings that in a slow way..

Comment: Did you watch this in the United States or in another country? And, as per RDFozz's question, could Cookie pick things up or talk?

Comment: Not the US. and yes I guess it can ...

Comment: ^_^ If not in the US, then where? It may help us figure this out if we know which country to target.

Comment: Does the 3D remake of "Budgie the Little Helicopter" look familiar? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFHjRIHFVE8

Comment: Qatar. Yes it looks similar to it but it has a human being as a friend.